# mysql json_extract function search in all position

Tags: mysql, json

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(mycolumn, '$.parent[0].child'))) > 0
```

this query is working

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(mycolumn, '$.parent[*].child'))) > 0
```

this query is not working

but when i want to put * instead of 0 my query is not working. i want to search key in all positions. first query only shows `"search key"` equal to only first (0) json

this is my json in mysql column

```
{"parent":[ { "child":"1,3", "type":"" },{ "child":"36,41", "type":"1" },{ "child":"52", "type":"1" } ]}
```

Comment: The latter call probably does not return a single comma separated list of values.

Comment: question is edited. last call does not return anything

Comment: What does it mean the query is not working? Does it throws some error? Or the output is not expected? What is `search key`? Won't `JSON_CONTAINS` be a better fit for you here?

Comment: question is edited. search key is what i want to search, for exampe i want to search 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a solution like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1, REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(column_name, '$.parent[*].child'), '[\\[\\]\\" ]', '')) > 0
```

[`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) returns a single value or a JSON array with all found values. The JSON array is not valid to use on [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). You first have to remove the `[`, `]` and `"` to get the comma separated list of all found values.

You can also use [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) to solve this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(column_name, 'one', '%,1,%', NULL, '$.parent[*].child') IS NOT NULL OR
  JSON_SEARCH(column_name, 'one', '1,%', NULL, '$.parent[*].child') IS NOT NULL OR
  JSON_SEARCH(column_name, 'one', '%,1', NULL, '$.parent[*].child') IS NOT NULL
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2fdfb8363fded3d49a83c6a4bf9dae81)